# Backtracking issue - can't figure out how to do this

Tags: javascript, backtracking

I am trying to make a small script (for a boardgame I am designing:P), which takes an object, which contains 1-4 random objects of a heroes attack damage, and possible targets, and calculates the best move for the heroes to make in an attack, by calculating each possible outcome, and weighing the results.

This is how my JavaScript object looks like:

```
var usedAttacks = {
    1: {
      attack: 2,
      attackableMonsters: Array(0, 1, 2)
    },
    2: {
     attack: 1,
     attackableMonsters: Array(0,1,3)
    },
    3:{
     attack: 4,
     attackableMonsters: Array(1,2,3)
    }
}
```

The keys in `usedAttacks` points to the hero ids that are making the attacks, the `attack` is the damage the hero can make, and the `attackableMonsters` array is an array, containing the id's of the monsters the hero can attack.

What I would like to do, is test each and every outcome of the given scenario, and return a `power` value at the end of each test, and in the end, select the scenario which results in the least `power` ammount.

```
Hero 1 -> Monster 0, Hero 2 -> Monster 0, Hero 3 -> Monster 1 = Power 10
Hero 1 -> Monster 0, Hero 2 -> Monster 0, Hero 3 -> Monster 2 = Power 11
Hero 1 -> Monster 0, Hero 2 -> Monster 0, Hero 3 -> Monster 3 = Power 8
Hero 1 -> Monster 0, Hero 2 -> Monster 1, Hero 3 -> Monster 1 = Power 10
...
```

Power is calculated by the attack power of the monsters that remain alive at the end of the heroes attack phase.

I feel that this problem must be solvable with some basic backtracking, but I just can't figure out how to start resolving it in javascript. I don't need a complete solution, if someone could provide some basic pointers on which I can start developing my own solution, I would be most grateful!

Comment: Are there any bounds? Like total hp or maximum number of turns?

Comment: No, no maximum number of turns, neither bounds. Logic would say that when Hero 1 reduces Monster 0's health to 0, there's no point in Hero 2 to attack Monster 0 again, but that move would result most likely in a greater power then some other results, where Hero 2 doesn't waste his/her attack, so that's not an issue either. Performance isn't an issue either, this is a homebrew script, used by only me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

We'll need an array with all the monster id's that we'll access using an index:

```
var monsters = [ /* all the monster IDs*/ ];
```

and we initialize a `target` object, with hero keys and monster values:

```
var target = {};
var numHeroes = 0;
for ( var i in usedAttacks )
    numHeroes++,
    target[i] = 0; // monsters array index.
```

and initialize the best solution with the first solution:

```
var minPower     = calcPower( target ),
    bestSolution = clone( target ); // store a copy, we don't want the solution changed.

function clone(obj) { return JSON.parse( JSON.stringify(obj) ); }
```

We then iterate over all combinations of monsters and heroes:

```
for ( var k = 1; i < monsters.length * numHeroes; k++) {
```

and we increment the monsters similar to an increment with carry:

```
    for ( var i in usedAttacks )                    // iterate hero IDs
        if ( target[i] + 1 >= monsters.length )
            target[i] = 0;                          // wrap around: carry (no break)
        else {
            target[i]++                             // no wrap:
            break;                                  //   abort.
        }
```

And we compare with the best solution and possibly update:

```
    var p = calcPower( target );
    if ( p < minPower ) {
        minPower = p;
        bestSolution = clone( target );
    }
}
```